# How to change equation numbering style

Tags: equations, numbering

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amssymb, amscd}
\begin{document}
    \chapter{Test}

    \begin{table}[h]
        \center
        \caption{Test}
        \begin{tabular}{l | r}
            Two & 2 \\
            Four & 4
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}

    Test equation:
    \begin{equation}
        a+b=c^2
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

It produces this:

[image]

Now I would like to change equation numbering style. I want (1-1) instead of (1.1). How can I do that? Also, I want to preserve numbering style for tables and figures (Table 1.1:) , I don't want (Table 1-1:)

Comment: You can try to redefine `\theequation` with `\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thechapter--\arabic{equation}}`. `:)`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I was looking for some hints in the `amsmath` documentation and found the following trick (adapted, of course):

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thechapter--\arabic{equation}}
```

If we look at the original definition of `\theequation`, we can find that it's more robust than our first attempt:

```
\long macro:->\ifnum \c@chapter >\z@ \thechapter .\fi \@arabic \c@equation
```

we can easily redefine it accordingly:

```
\makeatletter
\long\def\theequation{\ifnum \c@chapter > \z@ \thechapter --\fi \@arabic \c@equation}
\makeatother
```

Interestingly enough, there's another approach with the `etoolbox` package:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\theequation}{.}{--}{}{}
```

[image: Equation]

There we go. `:)`