# Need "(eq. 1)" style equation numbering

Tags: equations, numbering

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Changing the apperance of equation numbers with amsmath](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28903/changing-the-apperance-of-equation-numbers-with-amsmath)

I am editting a paper that requires the equation numbering to be of the format:

```
        F=m a       (eq. 1)
```

Is there a simple way to do this?  I have had trouble finding one.

Thanks

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)  Your question seems to be a duplicate of [this one](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/61756/13034), though I may be mistaken in thinking so.

Comment: We need to know whether you use packages like `amsmath` (yor question would be a duplicate, then) or not.

Comment: Seems so. 

For reference: 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{eq. \arabic{equation}}

This works.

Comment: And should this same format be used for cross-referencing?