# How to include chapter number in equation numbers

Tags: equations, classicthesis

I am trying to change the equation number style in `classicthesis` package. I followed the answers given in [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61756/how-to-change-equation-numbering-style) but it does not affect the equation style. I want to include the chapter number in the equation number. Could someone help me?

Comment: `\renewcommand\theequation{\thechapter.\arabic{equation}}`

Comment: `\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thechapter.\arabic{equation}}
\@addtoreset{equation}{chapter}
\makeatother`

Comment: I had tried those but it does not include the chapter number. The numbering is in the format: (1), (2), ....The numbering increases from chapter to chapter and the first equation in each chapter (except the first chapter) does not start from 1.

Comment: Then please add to your question a simple, yet *complete*, document allowing us to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I found out what the problem is. I should change the style after I declared `\usepackage{classicthesis}` in the file `classicthesis-config.tex`. With this in mind, changing the style works just great.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could load the `amsmath` package and use its `\numberwithin` command to achieve your objective:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{classicthesis}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\numberwithin{equation}{chapter}
\begin{document}
\chapter{First chapter}
\begin{equation}  \label{eq:pyth}
a^2+b^2=c^2
\end{equation}
Here's a cross-reference to equation \eqref{eq:pyth}.
\end{document}
```

---

Addendum: If you want to have the equation numbers look like `(1--1)` rather than like `(1.1)`, the `\theequation` macro needs to modified as well:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{classicthesis}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\numberwithin{equation}{chapter}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thechapter--\arabic{equation}}    

\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{2}
\chapter{Third chapter}
\begin{equation}  \label{eq:albert}
E=mc^2
\end{equation}
Here's a cross-reference to equation \eqref{eq:albert}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd consider also the dedicated `chngcntr` package

Comment: Isn't `\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thechapter--\arabic{equation}}` after `\numberwithin{equation}{chapter}` simpler than redefining `\numberwithin`?

Comment: @egreg - you're absolutely right. I'll modify the code accordingly.

Comment: If you are using the LyX version, it is enough to add the `\numberwithin` command in the `Document>Settings>LaTeX Preamble` menu path

Answer (score 0):

add “floatperchapter” at the option of \documentclass[]{}

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please be a bit more specific as to whether your proposed method works for arbitrary document classes or only specific ones.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This doesn't affect the equations though, does it?

Comment: @Mico I guess it should rather be an option to `classicthesis`, it is listed in the manual at least.