# Equations numbering in Springer journal

Tags: equations, numbering, sv-classes

In the template of a Springer journal there is no numbering procedure specified for the equations and there is only following lines as an example of an equation:

```
\begin{equation}
a^2+b^2=c^2
\end{equation}
```

This results in continuous numbering of equations. However, I've seen that in published papers of the same journal, the numbering restarts at each section.

Am I doing something wrong or it is the way it is supposed to be?

If numbering should restart at each section, how is that done?

Comment: Thanks to @luchonacho, [Here] (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/207532/reset-equation-numbering-after-each-section) is the answer to the second part of the question. However, I'd like to know if I should change the numbering or leave it be.

Comment: Is this not a matter of taste? If you are unsure, I would go for the one other papers in your field use. In any case, this is a very minor point, easy to correct in a future revision. So I would not bother very much with this.

Comment: In other papers numbering restarts too. So, I guess I'd just do that. Also, since I need that the number of sections to be included in equations number, [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106935/how-to-include-chapter-number-in-equation-numbers) was very helpful.

Comment: If you want to publish in a journal, just use the journal class as it is or ask your editor. Things like numbering by section will usually be done by the editor/publisher.

Comment: @Schweinebacke -- not *all* publishers (i know you said "usually").  at ams, the author is usually considered to have decided on the appropriate numbering style, so it won't be changed unless there's a real error.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: `svjour` is a Springer class. I've worked for Springer for several years. We have changed a lot of things, authors have done without asking the editor. And sometimes articles have been refused because of such changes.

Comment: @Schweinebacke -- i didn't say that editors don't change anything; they *do* make numerous changes in the body, and undo a lot of overzealous redefinitions.  but how to number equations -- continuously through an article or restart at every section break -- is not something an ams copyeditor would change, as long as what the author supplies is consistent and makes sense.  (somewhere in one of the ams manuals or templates, the instruction for how to `\numberwithin{equation}{section}` is given explicitly.  i don't remember exactly which one, but it's there, to be used by the author or not.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Springer is not AMS. I've never worked for AMS. But I have worked for Springer. The question talks about a Springer Journal. However, I would always recommend authors to ask the publisher/editor before changing a default of the publisher's class if the author guide does not explicitly document a changing option. And that was the intention of my comment. What do you have against asking the editor/publisher?

Answer (score 1):

Answer for your question "If numbering should restart at each section, how is that done?" is

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
```