# Prefix for \externaldocument references in \cleveref

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref

The question [Special case for last element with \foreach](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/164118/special-case-for-last-element-with-foreach) manually changed the references, and added the ability to have a prefix on references.  Can I do the same thing using `\cleveref`?

(Note: This is a `\cleveref` version of the question [Automatically add prefix to references from another document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112865/automatically-add-prefix-to-references-from-another-document))

**Approach 1:**
Have a `\crefex`, or renaming of `\cref`, which allows for the addition of a prefix.  For example

```
documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cleveref, xr}
\crefname{equation}{}{}
\crefname{figure}{figure}{Figure}
\newcommand{\crefex}[2][]  { %
\cref{#2} %But modify to add #1 as a prefix...
}
\begin{document}
    \section{sec1}\label{sec:sec1}
    \begin{equation}    1 = 1 \label{eq:eq1}    \end{equation}
    \begin{figure}\caption{fig1}\label{fig:fig1}\end{figure}
\crefex[TA.]{sec:sec1}, \crefex[TA.]{eq:eq1}, \crefex[TA.]{fig:fig1}
\end{document}
```

which should output as the references if `\crefex` was completed.

```
section TA.1, (TA.1), figure TA.1
```

**Approach 2:**
Alternatively, it could autodetect if there is an external reference, and add in some sort of a prefix defined as a variable?

Create a file called `external_document.tex` with the following text and compile it a few times.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefname{equation}{}{}
\crefname{figure}{figure}{Figure}
\begin{document}
    \section{sec1}\label{sec:sec1}
    \begin{equation}    1 = 1 \label{eq:eq1}    \end{equation}
    \begin{figure}\caption{fig1}\label{fig:fig1}\end{figure}
    \cref{sec:sec1}, \cref{eq:eq1}, \cref{fig:fig1}
\end{document}
```

Then create another file with:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cleveref, xr}
\crefname{equation}{}{}
\crefname{figure}{figure}{Figure}
\externaldocument[EX.]{external_document}
\begin{document}
    \section{sec1}\label{sec:sec1}
    \begin{equation}    1 = 1 \label{eq:eq1}    \end{equation}
    \begin{figure}\caption{fig1}\label{fig:fig1}\end{figure}
    \cref{sec:sec1}, \cref{eq:eq1}, \cref{fig:fig1}
    \subsection{External References}
    \cref{EX.sec:sec1}, \cref{EX.eq:eq1}, \cref{EX.fig:fig1}
\end{document}
```

This will correctly spit out both the internal and external references.  How might we add in autodetection of the external references which adds the prefix of the `\externaldocument` as described above?