# Align Showing Decimals

Tags: align, document-classes

taking a shot at writing my own document class right now. But my align is showing up like this:

[image]

instead of how it is usually looks, with just a (1) and not (1.1). Below is a test class where there's nothing except for the packages I'm using. When I recompile, it still looks like (1.1) instead of (1) so I'm guessing it has something to do with my packages. (Or maybe the book class just does this by default? I usually use article.) Anyone know how to change this to normal?

```
%
% Identification
%

\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{aligntest}[2021/11/18 Seeing if Align works]


%
% Class, Options, Packages
%

\LoadClass[a5paper]{book}


\RequirePackage{amsmath}
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
\RequirePackage{geometry}
\RequirePackage{mathptmx}
\RequirePackage{times}
\RequirePackage{titling}
```

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a Minimal Working Example, instead of a code snippet.

Comment: It's not the default so it must have been added somewhere, so binary search your class file. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/164669/250119

Comment: That is the default for book class, equations are numbered within chapters

Comment: unrelated but a new class shouldn't be forcing mathptmx and times they are ancient packages targetting the fonts available on a 1980s laser-writer, use newtxtext and newtxmath for a more reasonable Times Roman style font setup