# Pandoc equation numbering style

Tags: equations, numbering, pandoc

I use pandoc to render .pdf files from markdown.
Example input:

```
#Fudamental matrix
##Epipolar constraint in pixels

(@) $$(K_{0}^{-1}x)^{T}E(K_{1}^{-1}x')=0$$

(@) $$x^{T}((K_{0}^{-1})^{T}EK_{1}^{-1})x'=0$$

(@fundam) $$x^{T}F x'=0$$
```

Which renders my equations with the following numbers: (1), (2), (3).
I would like to have: (1.1), (1.2), (1.3), where the first number is the chapter nr, or even (1.1.1), (1.1.2), etc. with subchapters numbers as well.

I have a file templateAdd.tex with:

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\newcommand{\sectionbreak}{\clearpage}
```

I have tried adding the following to the file:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thechapter--\arabic{equation}}
```

as described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61756/how-to-change-equation-numbering-style), but this does not change the number rendering at all- it's still (1), (2), etc.

My pandoc call:

```
pandoc -s --mathjax --highlight-style pygments --number-sections --include-in-header   templateAdd.tex -o output\output.pdf -c style_print.css background.md
```

Comment: "It does not seem to work"... What do you get as output?

Comment: I just get the regular pandoc numbering like (11), as if it does not change anything in the settings

Comment: Is it possible to supply the community with a complete, [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) of your pandoc input file, together with the command-line operation you use to compile the input?

Comment: Done my best to be as detailed as possible, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is happening because pandoc is interpreting `(@)` signs as list markers, specifically an ordered list enclosed in parentheses. As can be seen if you inspect the latex output of pandoc:

Input:

```
(@) $$(K_{0}^{-1}x)^{T}E(K_{1}^{-1}x')=0$$
```

Output:

```
\begin{enumerate}
\def\labelenumi{(\arabic{enumi})}
\item
  \[(K_{0}^{-1}x)^{T}E(K_{1}^{-1}x')=0\]
\end{enumerate}
```

To get your desired numbering you will have to turn your formulas into latex equations. You can achieve this by using some inline latex in your markdown like this:

```
\begin{equation}
(K_{0}^{-1}x)^{T}E(K_{1}^{-1}x')=0
\end{equation}
```

and in your templateAdd.tex add the line:

```
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
```

you can change `section` to `subsection` or `subsubsection` to get (1.1) (1.1.1) or (1.1.1.1) numbering style.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is to use the [pandoc-eqnos](https://github.com/tomduck/pandoc-eqnos) filter, which processes attributed formulas. e.g.,

```
$$ (K_{0}^{-1}x)^{T}E(K_{1}^{-1}x')=0 $$ {#eq:foo}
```

When pandoc's output format is set to LaTeX or pdf, attributed formulas are converted by pandoc-eqnos to numbered LaTeX equations.  The equation may be referenced as Eq. @eq:foo.

To get the numbering style you want, you still need to put

```
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
```

in your LaTeX template and change `section` to `subsection` or `subsubsection` to get (1.1) (1.1.1) or (1.1.1.1) numbering style.