# Is it possible to include "Eq." in equation numbering?

Tags: equations, numbering, labels

Personally, I wanted to have "Eq." in front of the equation numbering. Also, I wanted to have the section numbering in front of the equation, so that the equations are numbered as (Eq. 3.1) instead of (1).

Anyone knows whether this is possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should look into loading the `mathtools` package (which, incidentally, automatically loads the `amsmath` package) and use its `\newtagform` and `\usetagform` macros.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\numberwithin{equation}{section} % how the equation numbers are formed
\newtagform{show_eq}{(Eq.\ }{)}  % how the equation numbers are displayed
\usetagform{show_eq}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\begin{equation}
1+1=3?
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
1+1\neq3
\end{equation}
\section{Some section or chapter without content...}
\section{Content!}
\begin{equation}
1+1=2
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
1+2=3
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image: example of what it should look like]

Comment: I tried it, it gives the exact same screenshot as what I had! :)) 
PS, can you maybe add the tag "equation-numbering"?

Comment: @TeunZijp - Thanks. I've gone ahead and added the 'labels' tag.

Comment: @TeunZijp - The output may indeed look the same. Going the `\newtagform`-`\settagform` route is slightly more robust, as these instructions may be run either before of after `\numberwithin{equation}{section}`; your solution, in contrast, requires a specific loading sequence.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible!

I started from [How to change equation numbering style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61756/how-to-change-equation-numbering-style), but this MWE should be sufficient to help you out.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % \numberwithin{equation} doesn't exist without this package.
\numberwithin{equation}{section} % This line resets equation numbering when starting a new section.
\renewcommand{\theequation}{Eq. \thesection.\arabic{equation}} % This line ads "Eq." in front of your equation numbering.
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\begin{equation}
1+1=3?
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
1+1\neq3
\end{equation}
\section{Some section or chapter without content...}
\section{Content!}
\begin{equation}
1+1=2
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
1+2=3
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image: example of what it should look like]

Unfortunately, the order of lines is crucial, because it is possible to override `\renewcommand{\theequation}{Eq. \thesection.\arabic{equation}}` with `\numberwithin{equation}{section}`, and you only get `(1.1)`.

Note that if `\numberwithin{equation}{section}` is left out, equation numbering continues after opening a new section, so it numbers like `(Eq. 1.1)`, `(Eq. 1.2)`, `(Eq. 3.3)`, `(Eq. 3.4)`, which is awkward.

Comment: Don't forget to use dot slash in Eq.\